# Trying to make loop exit , but it currently just continues looping for 100 times

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to make so when the looping of 100 hits on the character exits the loop when the life dice rolls to 0. How it currently is is all gets looped 100 times. I am not quite sure how I need to go about solving this, any tips would be helpful. My code is below.

```
function addChar(fname, lname, speed, agility, wep, outfit, mood) {
    this.fname = fname;
    this.lname = lname;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.agility = agility;
    this.wep = wep;
    this.outfit = outfit;
    this.mood = mood;

    this.special = function(specialMove) {
        specialMove();

    }

    this.jumpKick = function() {
        var jmpkckTimes = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 33 + 1)) + 33;

        document.write("He jumpkicks " + jmpkckTimes + " times. ");
        if (jmpkckTimes > 70) {
            document.write("He enters rage mode! ");
        } else {
            document.write("He does not have enough kicks for rage mode. ");
        }
    }

    this.hits = function() {
        var allHits = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 33 + 1)) + 33;
        document.write(" He gets attacked for " + allHits + " HP.");
    }
    this.lifes = function() {
        var life = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
        if (life > 0) {
            document.write(" The life dice rolls a " + life + ". You have survived! For now...");


        } else {
            document.write(" The life dice rolls a " + life + ". You have died!");

        }
    }
}
var myChar = new addChar('Johhny', 'Kicker', 10, 7, 'Ancient Greataxe', 'Barrows', 'angry');

document.write(myChar.fname + " " + myChar.lname + "'s speed is " + myChar.speed + "<br>");
document.write(myChar.fname + " " + myChar.lname + "'s agility is " + myChar.agility + "<br>");
document.write(myChar.fname + " " + myChar.lname + "'s weapon of choice is: " + myChar.wep + "<br>");
document.write(myChar.fname + " " + myChar.lname + " feels " + myChar.mood + "<br>");
document.write(myChar.fname + " " + myChar.lname + " attempts his special: ");
myChar.special(myChar.jumpKick)

for (i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    myChar.hits(myChar.allHits)
    myChar.lifes(myChar.lifes)
}

function myOutfit() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ("He is wearing " + myChar.outfit)

}
var start = Date.now();
var response = prompt("Do you think my character has what it takes?", "");
var end = Date.now();
var elapsed = (end - start) / 1000;
console.log("You took " + elapsed + " seconds" + " to type: " + response);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a way to communicate outside of the object, of what is happening inside the object.

For example, when something happens in a function, like lifes() or hits(), you should assign a value to a variable on the object to retain state. That way you can access the state from the for loop.

Example:

```
this.isAlive = true; // starting condition

this.lifes = function() {
    var life = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
    this.isAlive = (life > 0);
    if (this.alive) {
        document.write('you survived');
    } else {
        document.write('you died');
    }
```

Now in your for loop, you can access isAlive:

```
// loop until 100 attempts or you die, which ever comes first
for (i = 1; i < 101 && myChar.isAlive; i++) {
    myChar.hits(myChar.allHits)
    myChar.lifes(myChar.lifes)
}
```

Comment: I just tried your corrections, but they did not seem to correct the solution. So i need to further edit?

Comment: @DrewStenger This is an example, not an implementation. Your issue was about exiting the loop early based on the current state of the object.  It is up to you how you implement that logic.

Comment: @DrewStenger we are not minions. besides, the SO rules explicitely state that.

Answer (score 0):

well in general you can break out of foor loops aswell as prevent further execution of a foor loop and continue the next iteration:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (i == 4) continue;
    if (i == 8) break;
    console.log(i);
}
```

this will basically print: 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7
(as you can see it kind of skipped 4)
(it will also work in while / do while loops)

so in your case you could check if the return value of one of your functions is true or false or do some other kind of conditional checking in order to break out of the loop.

or similar to how Rob Brander wrote in his answer:

```
var maxTurns = 100;

var turns = 0;
while (myChar.isAlive && ++turns <= maxTurns) {
    myChar.hits();
    myChar.lifes();
}
console.log("character is: " + myChar.isAlive ? "alive" : "dead");
console.log("after: " + turns + " turns.");
```

Comment: I have edited my code accordingly, however I am getting the same output.